# Como adicionar um botão que execute um aplicativo com php?

Tags: php

Como faço pra criar um botão pra executar um aplicativo em meu servidor através do php? O que desejo é através de uma página web eu consiga executar um script ou aplicativo (*.vbs, *.exe ) no meu servidor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tem várias formas de executar um programa pelo php. Porém, se o servidor não estiver habilitado, nem todo o programa poderá ser executado.

**Opção 1** - *Usando **[exec()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.exec.php)***

Com esse comando ele executará o programa e retornará a ultima linha do resultado.

```
$retorno = exec('wscript "dir/arquivo.vbs"');
```

---

**Opção 2** - *Usando o **[COM](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.com.php)***

Usar o `COM` pode ser interessante se você for executar programas windows. Ele é próprio para isso. Você pode executar programas em word por exemplo.

```
$obj = new COM ( 'WScript.Shell' );
$obj->Run ( 'cmd /C ' . "wscript.exe dir/arquivo.vbs", 0, FALSE );
```

---

**Opção 3** - *Usando o **[shell_exec](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.shell-exec.php)***

O `shell_exec` é bem parecido com o `exec`, porém ele executará um programa via shell e retornará toda sua saída.

```
$retorno = shell_exec (start wscript "dir/arquivo.vbs");
```

---

**Opção 4** - *Usando o **[system](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.system.php)***

Também é parecido com o `exec`, porém ela retorna o resultado na tela para o usuário se não for atribuído uma variável ao comando.

```
system("dir/arquivo.vbs");
```